# How to expand $\log(z)^{-n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, summation, euler-maclaurin

For $\left|z\right|<1$ we have

$$S_2(z):=\dfrac{1}{(z-1)^2}+\dfrac{1}{z-1}= 0\,z^0+1\,z^1+2\,z^2+3\,z^3+\dots$$

and then

$$\lim_{z\,\to\,1}\left(S_2(z)-\frac{1}{\log(z)^2}\right)=-\dfrac{1}{12}.$$

A connection to the Euler-MacLaurin formula can be motivated by comparing the $z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$-derivatives of

- $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=-\frac{1}{z-1}$
- $\int_0^\infty z^t\,{\mathrm d}t=\int_0^\infty {\mathrm e}^{t\log(z)}\,{\mathrm d}t=-\frac{1}{\log(z)}$.

---

For a generalization coming from higher derivatives I want to know the closed form expressions

$S_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{s_{n,k}}{(z-1)^{n-k}}$,

so that

$\lim_{z\to 1}\left(S_n(z)-\frac{1}{\log(z)^n}\right)$

is finite. This function is the divergent part of the expansion of $\frac{1}{\log(z)^n}$.

[image]

Mathematica tells me the coefficients start out as $1,\, \frac{n}{2},\, \frac{n}{2}\frac{1}{12}(3n-5),\dots$. So indeed, for $n=2$ this means we have $s_{2,0}=1$ for a double pole, $s_{2,1}=1$ for a single pole and then the finite part of the log-expansion is $\frac{1}{12}$.

---

Thoughts:

I could use
$\log(z)=1-\left(1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,(-1)^{k}\,\frac{1}{k}\,(z-1)^k\right)$

and the expansion for $\frac{1}{1-x}$, but then I end up with two levels of taking arbitrary powers. I know there is [this formula for exponentiation of power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Operations_on_formal_power_series), but using it twice on the alternating coefficients on a modified log seems intractable.

Playing around makes me think expanding 
$\left(\dfrac{\log(z)}{1-z}\right)^n=\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,(-1)^{k}\,\frac{1}{k}\,(z-1)^{k-1}\right)^n$

is easier and leads me to the desired result, but I still end up with an expression where I must use the above formula on a sum and then I have iterated sum.

Is there an approachable way of deriving the expansion of $\frac{1}{\log(z)^n}$ up to the first positive order in $z-1$?

I'm now thinking maybe one can also obtain the result by by taking n'th derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Although the Taylor series is not about $z=1$, it works for many other $z$:

$$\ln^{-n}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(z-a)^k}{k!}\frac{d^k}{da^k}\ln^{-n}(a)$$

After a [pattern](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5Bln%28z%29%5E-n%2C%7Bz%2C10%7D%5D) with [Stirling S1 $S_n^{(m)}$](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/23/02/) and [factorial power $a^{(b)}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factorialpower)

$$\frac{d^k}{da^k}\ln^{-n}(a)=\sum_{m=1}^k\frac{S_k^{(m)}(-n)^{(m)}\ln^{-m-n}(a)}{a^k}$$

with an [example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5Bln%28x%29%5E-e%2C%7Bx%2C3%7D%5D%2C+sum%5B%28FactorialPower%5B-e%2C+m%5D+Log%5Bx%5D%5E%28-m+-+e%29+StirlingS1%5B3%2C+m%5D%29%2Fx%5E3%2C%7Bm%2C1%2C3%7D%5D). Therefore:

$$\boxed{\ln^{-n}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^k\frac{S_k^{(m)}(-n)^{(m)}\ln^{-m-n}(a)(z-a)^k}{a^kk!}}$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22z%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22Plot%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotlowerrange%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22plot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%7Bln%28z%29%5E-4%2Csum%5B%28z-1%2F2%29%5Ek%2Fk%21+sum%5B%28FactorialPower%5B-4%2C+m%5D+Log%5B1%2F2%5D%5E%28-m+-+4%29+StirlingS1%5Bk%2C+m%5D%29%2F%281%2F2%29%5Ek%2C%7Bm%2C1%2C20%7D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%7D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotupperrange%22%7D+-%3E%221%22) where if $k$’s upper bound is $\infty$, then the sums are interchangeable. Also, there is a [summation formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/23/02/0001/):

$$\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{n!}{k!}S_k^{(n)}(z-1)^n=\ln^n(z)$$